# How to reduce the size of an image when uploading it to a project

Tags: php, laravel

I need help to reduce the size of an image. I know that it is necessary to `resize()` but I do not understand where to insert it.

Controller:

```
$target_file_name = public_path().'/upload/'.Str::random(10);
$type = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
$type = stristr($type, '/');
$type = substr($type, 1);
$response = array();
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name.'.'.$type);
$dopysk->ydostak =basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );
```

Comment: Plese have a look at [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

Comment: Are you talking about image size or image dimensions? Image size is for example 1 MB and you want to reduce it to 500 kB for example. Or maybe image is 1000x1000px and you want to reduce it to 500x500px ?

Comment: to reduce the resolution

Comment: As said @RishiRaut you must see to [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) composer package for resize your image size.